# flask and flask_login - organizing code

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am currently coding up a simple web application using flask and flask_login, and got stuck due to a code organisation problem.

```
import flask
import flask_login

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

The above works. The problem arises because I want to separate authentication related code from the main flask application code. In other words, I want `my_auth.py` that imports `flask_login` and initializes the `login_manager`, and I want `main.py` to `import my_auth`, and NOT have to import `flask_login`.

The problem is that `login_manager.init_app(app)` requires the main flask `app` to be passed in, and this clear separation seems difficult. Thus my questions are:

1. Is what I am asking for even possible? If so, how?
2. If what I am asking for is not possible, what is currently accepted as the best practice in organising such code?

Comment: Can u provide your web app folder structure?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following, if `main.py` and `my_auth.py` reside on same directory:

`my_auth.py`:

```
import flask_login

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
```

`main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from my_auth import login_manager

app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

Comment: Ugh, I realised that I asked the wrong question. You did answer the above question, however, so I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @wookie919...You can clarify more your intended objective by editing your question with more details.

Comment: No, that would complicate this question too much. Will raise another question which is more to the point. Maybe you can help me with that one too. :)

Comment: Alrghity, go ahead.. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930978/flask-and-flask-login-avoid-importing-flask-login-from-main-code