# flask and flask_login - avoid importing flask_login from main code

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am currently coding up a simple web application using flask and flask_login. This is `main.py`:

```
import flask
import flask_login

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
@flask_login.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

The above code works. The problem arises because I want to separate authentication related code from the main flask application code. In other words, I want `my_auth.py` that imports `flask_login`, and I want `main.py` to `import my_auth`, and NOT have to import `flask_login`.

The problem is with the `@flask_login.login_required` decorator. If I do not import `flask_login` from `main.py`, is it still possible to somehow "wrap" the main `index()` function with `login_required`?

(I've actually asked a wrong question before, which may still be relevant: [flask and flask_login - organizing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930604/flask-and-flask-login-organizing-code))

Comment: Why you do not want to import `flask_login` into `main.py`?

Comment: Separation of concerns - trying to understand how cleanly I can separate the login side of things from the main code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file `my_auth.py`

```
# my_auth.py

import flask_login

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()

# create an alias of login_required decorator
login_required = flask_login.login_required
```

and in file `main.py`

```
# main.py

import flask
from my_auth import (
    login_manager,
    login_required
)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
login_manager.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Maybe this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: @wookie919 yeah sure. I think actually this much of separation of code is enough if you need so.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Akshay's answer works.

While waiting for an answer, however, I've also found a workaround(?) that does not rely on using the decorator:

In `main.py`:

```
@SVS.route("/")
def index():
    if not my_auth.is_authenticated():
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login'))

    return "Hello World!"
```

In `my_auth.py`:

```
def is_authenticated():
    return flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated
```